# Ionic (Angular) - Read a file and parse its content

Tags: angular, file, ionic-framework

I am working on a project where I want to read content from a file and want to get useful information from its data and display it to user, for example suppose I have a text file (.txt) in which there are 10 lines like "sham went to school", "Rohan bought a new pen" etc.
I know this is a silly example but just want to deliver the basic idea. I want to read this content in Ionic and want to show it to user in a beautiful and elegant way after some sort of manipulation. 
I am using cordova file chooser plugin, now want to read file content as I mentioned above.
Any help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance :)

I have tried `http` get function to read a file but don't know how to use it with choosen file. I made below function and now I have no idea how to pass that file as argument to this function

```
public readFile(file) {
    this.http.get(file).pipe(map(res => res.text()))                
     .subscribe(data => {                         
      this.requests = data.split('\n');
      this.testtext = this.requests[20];
});
```

Comment: Are you referring to file upload?

Comment: @Aragorn thanks for reply, yes I am referring to file upload, I want to parse content of that uploaded file.

Comment: Why are you doing http.get to upload a file? Hence my question, uploading a file or getting it from a service?

Comment: I was totally blank for this concept so I made some random google search and found this solution, I just want to upload a text file and want to parse its content and want to display it in the view after some manipulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a file upload function you can use. This uses `FileReader`. [read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

Add this to your component file and use it in template by binding it to an event.

I've added as much comment as I thought would be useful, but let me know if you get confused in any line.

```js
public uploadFile(files: FileList): void {
    let results = [];
    if (files && files.length > 0) {
        const file: File = files.item(0); //assuming only one file is uploaded
        console.log('Uploaded file, Filename:' + file.name + 'Filesize:' + file.size + 'Filetype:' + file.type);
        const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(file);
        reader.onload = (e) => {
        const fileContent: string = reader.result as string;
        console.log('fileContent:' + fileContent);
        const lines: string[] = fileContent.split('\n'); //this depends on your line end character, I'm using \n in general
        //lines is an array of string, such as "Sham went to school", loop over it and process as you like
        };
    }
}
```

You can use it in your template, like:

```html
<input type="file" (change)="uploadFile($event.target.files)">
```

Comment: wow! It works, @Aragorn brother, you are a life saver. Thanks a million.